# Hiding locale parameter in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, routes

i want to implement the following behaviour:

if the users browser-language is e.g. `EN`, he should be redirected to a the url `http://foo.bar/hello`, if the browser-language is `DE` then to `http://foo.bar/hallo`.

so how do i need to set my routes to redirect the user to the right language (e.g. when an english user requests the DE route and vice versa) and how can i set a hidden locale parameter, so i can load the right view in the controller?

i want to use the same controller for both languages (one method per page), but localized views (foo.en.html.erb etc.)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that what you want to try to get is a good idea, and I will explain that here. I don't understand why you would choose a different approach from the ones that are provided by Rails out of the box, and explained in details in the ["Internationalization Guide, Sections 2.3 and further"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale).

Here are the arguments:

- Rails provides at least 3 different ways to change the locale:

  1. Getting it from parameters: `http://my.example.com/books?locale=de`
  2. Getting it from the sub-domain: `http://de.example.com/books`
  3. Client supplied application, like the accept-header
- All have the advantage that the controller **and action** will be the same, which is what you normally want to have.
- There are helper methods if you want to change your behavior depending on the locate: `locale`, ...
- However, you may localize views as a whole if you want to do: see [localized  views](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views). This will perhaps lead to a duplication in view code.
- Or you use the translation and localization API as in `I18n.t 'store.title'` or `I18n.l Time.now`.

A hidden locale parameter has the disadvantage that it is not obvious (for the user) which locale is used.

Comment: you are right, the subdomain approach fits quite well. haven't thought about that. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to translate your routes in addition to set the locale, you may have a look to the [translate_routes](https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes) gem.

The README explains how you can set the locale from your translation hello/hallo.